# Can two players share one Scribblenauts Unlimited cartridge with two systems?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, scribblenauts-unlimited

My kids each have their own Nintendo 2DS, and one of them has the Scribblenauts Unlimited game.  We were hoping that they could each play the game using the same cartridge (not at the same time, of course), but when we moved the cartridge, it appears that the game save data is on the cartridge, not the system.

I know that Pokemon games all put the save data on the cartridge, and that you can't use one cartridge to play more than one game at a time, even with separate systems.

Is Scribblenauts Unlimited the same way?  Is there a way that the game save data can be moved to the system so that they can share the game?

Also, is it pretty typical for 3DS games that the game saves are on the cartridge (preventing game sharing), or are most 3DS games saved on the system (making Pokemon and Scribblenauts unusual)?

Comment: Yes;  Game data is saved on the cartridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Scribblenauts Unlimited, game data is saved on the cartridge. Therefore, two players cannot share one cartridge and play separate games.

According to [this post from Nintendo](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/337/~/do-nintendo-3ds-games-save-to-the-sd-card-%2F-microsd-card-%2F-system-memory%3F), it is typical for 3DS game save data to be saved to the game cartridge, not the system memory.

Answer (score 0):

From a [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272083/can-two-players-share-one-scribblenauts-unlimited-cartridge-with-two-systems#comment381760_272083) by [Ramhound](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/24871/ramhound):

> Yes; Game data is saved on the cartridge.